# Unable to perform TFVC to GIT import on VSTS

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to import a specific TFS branch (without history) to GIT using "Import from TFVC" function available after creating an empty GIT repository in VSTS. The error I am getting is:

`There is no item in the given path which can be imported`

VSTS redirects me to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=839462 but there is no description of this error, it's a general import guide.

The branch I am referencing during the import has many projects and is about 500MB in size (this is the size on disk after I fetch the branch to an empty folder).

What can I do to perform the import using the import tool?

If this fails can I simply create a local GIT repo on my disk, where i have the TFS branch, connect it to the newly created remote repo and push everything there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is the tip, you can clone your empty Git repo, add the files from TFVC, and push the repo using standard Git commands. Or you can `git init` a new local repo, add a remote pointing to your empty repo, and push that way.

No need for the import tool.